# How to find a pattern and replace it with XML tag while removing the pattern in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

What I want to do is find all words that are any sequences of alphabetic characters separated by underscores, for instance:

```
L_L_L
```

And turn them into tags like:

```
<acronym>L L L</acronym>
```

The acronyms can be any length, so I'm struggling with finding all instances.

Comment: Can you expand on "words that look like"?  Is it any sequences of alphabetic characters separated by underscores?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your sample acronym represents "any sequence of English capital letters separated by underscores" you could do the following:

```ruby
def replace_acronyms(str)
  str.gsub(/\b([A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)+)\b/) do |m,g1|
    '<acronym>' + $1.gsub(/_/,' ') + '</acronym>'
  end
end

replace_acronyms('Foo L_L_L bar.') # => "Foo <acronym>L L L</acronym> bar."
```